# AIX "rmdev -rl <disk>" equivalent command in RedHat Linux

Tags: linux, devices

We use `rmdev -dl hdisk10` to remove the disk from server end in AIX. In such a way, do we have any command available in RedHat linux to remove LUN from server end?

Is there an equivalent command for AIX's `rmdev -rl <disk>` in RedHat Linux?

Comment: It helps if you read what you write, apart from 100% ungrammatical sentences, you would have noticed that `<disk>` did not show up.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish at the end?

Comment: It's worth pointing out, that AIX command isn't valid.  It would be `rmdev -Rl`, not `-rl`.

Comment: Ok. I'm sorry guys for no clarity question.

My question is, we use rmdev -dl hdisk10 to remove the disk from server end in AIX. In such a way, do we have any command available in RedHat linux to remove LUN from server end.

Answer (score 1):

The closest equivalent I can think of, is,

`echo 1 > /sys/block/device-name/device/delete` where the device name is sdb or whatever.

You need to ensure (as with AIX) that the device is unmounted (removed from LVM, etc.), before you do this.

[Redhat has a full description of the process](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Online_Storage_Reconfiguration_Guide/removing_devices.html).